# Unable to recreate Unity container-controlled object (EF dbcontext) manually

Tags: dependency-injection, unity-container

I am using Unity HierarchicalLifetimeManager to resolve EF dbcontext with constructor injection.

For some reason i want to recreate the dbcontext manually, e.g. after 1000 records committed.

I have tried `LifetimeManager.SetValue(newValue)` but it does not work, still the constructor injection injects the old dbcontext.

What i am missing here?

Comment: Answer: After called LifetimeManager.SetValue(newValue), i have to resolve the instances which are all sharing the dbcontext.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found the solution.

After called `LifetimeManager.SetValue(newValue)` i have to resolve the instances which are all sharing the dbcontext.